# Ask Gregorian Calendar for hour of day in java

Tags: java, datetime, gregorian-calendar, hour, minute

I'm using a Gregorian Calendar to set a specific date and time to an application using the set function of the Gregorian Calendar.  When i use the getTime() method, it gives me the right output however when i try to access the Hour_Of_Day and Minute it gives a wrong number.

```
    Calendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
    time.set(2010, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 7, 20,0);       
    hour = time.HOUR_OF_DAY;
    minute = time.MINUTE;
```

The hour gives an output of 11 and the minute gives an a value of 12.
Any suggestions on how to fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: This is a good one. Does is always return 11? : - )  Here's more information : http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is just assigning hour/minute to constants.  You need to call Calendar.get(int):

```
hour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minute = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myGregCal
    .toZonedDateTime()  // Convert from legacy class GregorianCalendar to modern ZonedDateTime.
    .getHour()          // Get hour-of-day, 0-23.
```

## java.time

Much easier with the modern java.time classes that replace those troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in a specific time zone with a resolution of nanoseconds.

Convert from your `GregorianCalendar` using new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Or start fresh without the `GregorianCalendar` class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2010 , Month.JANUARY , 1 , 7 , 20 , 0 , 0 , z );
```

If you want to work with just the time-of-day portion, extract a `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime localTime = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If you really want the integer numbers of hours and minutes, you can interrogate for those.

```
int hour = zdt.getHour();
int minute = zdt.getMinute();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).